# XHTML Strict alternative to putting block elements inside an anchor

Tags: html, css, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm trying to make a couple of DIVs clickable in its entirety. I tried this...

```
<div id="features" class="threeSplit">
    <div id="box1">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <h3>Watch TV anywhere</h3>
            <p>While you're out of town, you can still watch live television.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <a href="install">
            <h3>No subscription</h3>
            <p>Save your money. VRT and RTBF channels are available at no cost.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
        <a href="coverage">
            <h3>Picking up channels</h3>
            <p>Television channels can be picked up from antennas near you.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click here for [live](http://localhost.sharedcopy.com/codeign_test/7f34671b610f3bea2dc90153d927574c.html) version. Now, XHTML 1.0 Strict does not like that I put block elements inside an anchor tag. Is there a better way that does comply with XHTML Strict? I know the page still contains lots of validation errors, but this is only a quick 'n dirty mockup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `onclick` event within the div elements...

```
<div id="box2" onclick='window.location = "install"'>
    <h3>No subscription</h3>
    <p>Save your money. VRT and RTBF channels are available at no cost.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if the onclicked does not work then put the window.location="instal" into its own script and call the script within the div tag.

Comment: I see two drawbacks: this trick requires JavaScript and doesn't show the special mouse cursor that you get with anchor tags unless you fix that with more JavaScript.

Comment: @Peter, actually you don't need js to fix the cursor issue. cursor: pointer; in CSS works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could either

- Put `span` tags inside of your `a` tags, instead of `h3` and `p`, and style them accordingly
- Use javascript to catch the click and follow the link, doing away with the `a` tag

The last option, I would say, is more elegant.

Comment: Dont ever use spans instead of "propper" tags. Your mark up should be correct using the right tags.

Comment: Sure, but it would validate, so it would be a solution. More so if you have the requirement of a no-JS alternative.